# If $f_{n}$ has a dense image, then $\bigcap (f_{1}\circ\cdots\circ f_{n})(X_{n})$ is dense

Tags: general-topology, the-baire-space

Let $\{(X_{n}, d_{n})\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of complete metric spaces and $\{f_{n}: X_{n}\to X_{n − 1}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of continuous functions. If $f_{n}$ has a dense image for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, show that $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(f_{1}\circ f_{2}\circ \cdots \circ f_{n}) (X_{n})$ is dense at $X_{0}$.

My attemps:
if $f_{n}$ has a dense image then $\overline{f_{n}(X_{n})}=X_{n-1}$ I want to show that
$$\overline{\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(f_{1} \circ f_{2} \circ \cdots \circ f_{n})(X_{n})} = X_{0}. $$
Let $F_{n}=(f_{1}\circ f_{2} \circ \dots ◦ f_{n})(X_{n})$. By induction, I see that $F_{n+1} ⊆ F_{n} ⊆ X_{0}$. Indeed, if $n=1$, then
$$F_{2}=(f_{1}\circ f_{2})(X_{2})=f_{1}(f_{2}(X_{2}))\subseteq f_{1}(\overline{f_{2}(X_{2}}))=f_{1}(X_{1})=F_{1}$$
if we assume that $F_{k+1}\subseteq F_{k}\subset X_{0}$. Then,
$$F_{k+2} = (f_{1} \circ f_{2} \circ \cdots \circ f_{k+1} \circ f_{k+2})(X_{k+2}) = (f_{1} \circ f_{2} \circ \cdots \circ f_{k+1})(f_{k+2}(X_{k+2}))\subseteq (f_{1} \circ f_{2} \circ \cdots \circ f_{k+1})(\overline{f_{k+2}(X_{k+2})}) = (f_{1} \circ f_{2} \circ \cdots \circ f_{k+1})(X_{k+1})= F_{k+1}\subseteq F_{k}\subseteq X_{0}$$
from the above we have
$$\cdots\subseteq F_{n+1}\subseteq F_{n} \subseteq \cdots \subset F_{2}\subseteq F_{1}$$
then
$$\cdots\subseteq \overline{F_{n+1}}\subseteq \overline{F_{n}} \subseteq \cdots \subset \overline{F_{2}}\subseteq \overline{F_{1}}=X_{0}$$
then
$$\overline{\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}F_{n} }\subseteq \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\overline{F_{n}}\subseteq X_{0} .$$

is my reasoning correct?.I've been thinking that Biare's theorem could be used, but I don't know if it's possible since $F_{n}'s$ don't necessarily open.

If it is, how could the other containment prove?. I appreciate any help

Comment: Yes, the exercise indicates that the images of the $f_ {n}$ are dense, but it doesn't say anything about its pre-images

Comment: oh I see. Do you have any suggestions for exercise?

Comment: Does it follow that your maps are open? Maybe I'm just not inventive enough, but I can't think of a counterexample.

Comment: This comes down to a countable intersection of dense subsets. For $x \in X_0$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ you find some $x_1 \in X_1$ with $d(f_1(x_1),x)<\varepsilon/2$. And some $x_2 \in X_2$ with $d(f_1(f_2(x_2)),f_1(x_1))<\varepsilon/4$, etc... Now the $f_1(f_2(...(x_n))$ form a Cauchy sequence coverging to a point $x_{\infty}$, that is contained in $\bigcap ...$. By the geometric series you can show, that $d(x,x_{\infty}) \leq \varepsilon$. I can make this into an answer later if you want.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. I will try to demonstrate.  I would like to see a bit more detail in an answer though, thanks! @Julian Quast

Comment: I just realized, that i proved something else, that isn't helpful here, sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slight reformulation of @supinf's answer, elucidating the skipped parts:

---

**Setting.** For $0 \leq i \leq j$, define the function $f^{i\leftarrow j} $ by the composition

$$ X_i \stackrel{f^{i\leftarrow j}}{\longleftarrow} X_{j}
\quad = \quad
X_i \stackrel{f_{i+1}}{\longleftarrow} X_{i+1} \stackrel{f_{i+2}}{\longleftarrow} \cdots  \stackrel{f_j}{\longleftarrow} X_j, $$

i.e.,

\begin{align*}
f^{i\leftarrow j}
:= \begin{cases}
f_{i+1} \circ \dots \circ f_{j}, & \text{if $i < j$}, \\
\operatorname{id}_{X_j}, & \text{if $i = j$}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

In particular, note that $f^{j \leftarrow j+1} = f_{j+1}$ and $f^{i\leftarrow j} \circ f^{j \leftarrow k} = f^{i \leftarrow k}$. Using this, OP's question boils down to showing that

$$ \bigcap_{j\geq 0} f^{0\leftarrow j}(X_j) $$

is dense in $X_0$. We establish by showing that in fact the following subset

$$ X^{0\leftarrow} := \biggl\{ z_0 \in X_0 : \text{$\exists$ $\{z_j\}_{j\geq 0} \in \prod_{j\geq 0}X_j$ s.t. $z_j = f_{j+1}(z_{j+1})$ for all $j \geq 0$} \biggr\} $$

is dense in $X_0$.

(*Note.* It is clear that $X^{0\leftarrow} \subseteq \bigcap_{j\geq 0} f^{0\leftarrow j}(X_j)$. What is not clear to me is whether they coincide or not.)

**Proof.** Fix any open ball $B(x_0,\epsilon) \subseteq X_0$. Then we construct a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ recursively as follows:

> Suppose $ x_n \in X_n $ has been chosen. Since $f_{n+1}(X_{n+1})$ is dense in $X_{n}$, we can find a sequence $\{y_k\}_{k\geq 1}$ in $X_{n+1}$ such that
>
> $$\lim_{k\to\infty} f_{n+1}(y_k) = x_{n}.$$
>
> Then for each $j = 0, \dots, n$, by continuity of $f^{j\leftarrow n}$ and $d_j(\cdot, \cdot)$, we have
>
> $$ \lim_{k\to\infty} d_j\bigl( f^{j\leftarrow n}(x_n), f^{j\leftarrow n}(f_{n+1}(y_k)) \bigr) = 0. $$
>
> From this observation, we can pick $x_{n+1} \in X_{n+1}$ so that
>
> $$ d_j\bigl( f^{j \leftarrow n}(x_n), f^{j \leftarrow n+1}(x_{n+1}) \bigr) < \epsilon 2^{-n-1} $$
>
> for each $0 \leq j \leq n$.

Schematically, $x_n$'s are chosen as:

[image: Schematic figure]

Now we make several observations:

- By the construction, for each $j \geq 0$, the sequence $\{ f^{j\leftarrow n}(x_n) \}_{n = j}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy in $X_j$, and so,
  $$ z_j := \lim_{n\to\infty} f^{j\leftarrow n}(x_n) $$
  exists in $X_j$.
- For each $j \geq 0$, we have
  $$ z_j
  = \lim_{n\to\infty} f^{j\leftarrow n}(x_n)
  = \lim_{n\to\infty} f_{j+1}(f^{(j+1)\leftarrow n}(x_n))
  = f_{j+1}(z_{j+1}). $$
  In particular, $z_0 \in X^{0\leftarrow}$.
- We have
  \begin{align*}
  d_0(x_0, z_0)
  &= \lim_{N\to\infty} d_0(x_0, f^{0\leftarrow N}(x_N)) \\
  &\leq \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} d_0(f^{0\leftarrow n}(x_n), f^{0\leftarrow n+1}(x_{n+1})) \\
  &< \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \epsilon 2^{-n-1} \\
  &= \epsilon,
  \end{align*}
  and so, $z_0 \in B(x_0, \epsilon)$.

This proves that $B(x_0, \epsilon) \cap X^{0\leftarrow} \neq \varnothing$ for any open ball $B(x_0, \epsilon)$ in $X_0$, establishing the desired claim.

Comment: If for every $ n \in \mathbb {N}, $ exists a open set $ U_{n} \subseteq {X_{n}} $ such that $ \overline {f_{n} ({U_{n}})} = X_{n-1}, $ then is the previous result still valid?

Comment: @Darkmaster, What are the other assumptions on $X_n$'s and $f_n$'s? Still assuming that $X_n$'s are complete and $f_n$'s are continuous, then your assumption implies that the image of $f_n$ is dense in $X_{n-1}$, so the above result applies.

Comment: Let $\{(X_{n},d_{n})\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of complete metric spaces. If $\{f_{n}\colon X_{n}\to X_{n-1}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of functions continuous such that there is an open set $ U_ {n} \subseteq {X_ {n}} $ and
\begin{equation}
\overline{f_{n}(U_{n})}=X_{n-1},\,\forall\,n\in\mathbb{N},
\end{equation}
show that $\overline{\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{(f_{1}\circ\cdots\circ f_{n})(U_{n})}}=X_{0}.$

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a solution but its rather technical.
The following is more of a sketch than a solution with full details.

Let $x_0\in X$ and $\varepsilon>0$ be given.

In a first step, one has to
construct points $y_{k,m}$ for $m,k\in\Bbb N_0$ with $k\leq m$
such that
$$
\begin{aligned}
y_{k,m} &\in X_k
\\
y_{0,0} &= x_0
\\
f_k(y_{k,m}) &= y_{k-1,m}
\quad\forall m\geq k\geq 1,
\\
d_k(y_{k,m},y_{k,m+1}) &< \varepsilon 2^{-m-1}
\quad\forall m\geq k\geq 0.
\end{aligned}
$$
(This requires continuity of these functions
and density of the images, and can be done recursively in $m$.
This step requires some technical details that I skipped here.)
Then, one can show that $\{y_{k,m}\}_{m\geq k}$ is a Cauchy sequence
for each $k$.
Thus, there exist points $z_k$ with
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty} y_{k,m} = z_k \quad\forall k\geq0.
$$
Due to continuity of $f_k$, one can show that
$f_k(z_k)=z_{k-1}$ holds.
Therefore, we have
$$
z_0\in F_k \quad\forall k\geq 1
\qquad\text{and therefore}\qquad
z_0 \in F_\infty:=\bigcap_{k\in\Bbb N} F_k.
$$
Finally, one can also show that
$$d_0(z_0,x_0)<\varepsilon$$
holds. Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, this shows that
$F_\infty$ is dense in $X_0$.